# How to reduce noises of light reflection on the static object in video?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, denoise

I am not sure what is this problem called. There are many noises of light reflection on the ground. They are different between frames. How do I reduce it? Or how to make it more realistic?

Can texture baking help? I know there are tutorial on this topic but I am not sure if it is relevant.

[image]

My settings:

[image]

Comment: please check an answer as correct (click on checkmark left to the answer) if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

128 samples on this setup is spreading it quite thin. The new default sample count is high for a reason: more samples means less noise, and with a better Cycles engine, shorter times for samples means we can afford more of them. Set the count to at least 512.

Comment: I am rendering thousands of frames and it takes too long to render on my 3060. Other solutions?

Comment: there is no other solution, maybe a different rendering engine instead of cycles, cycles simply needs more samples and that's it... In still render you don't need too much samples, but for video like this it is simply needed

Comment: @MikoCG that's not necessarily true.  There are several things you can do with cycles to improve noise without increasing samples, depending on what the source of the noise is.

Answer (score 1):

I would disable the render denoiser, add a denoiser pass, and use the compositing denoiser.  It seems to do a better job.

Disable the render denoiser in *Render Properties* of the properties editor:

[image: disable render denoiser]

Enable the *Denoiser Data* pass in the *View Layer Properties* of the properties editor:

[image: enable denoiser]

Here's a staring point for a denoiser pass in the *Compositor*:

[image: Compositor denoising]